# Style a button in EXTJS

Tags: css, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a button. and i need to align it to the right, make the font size increase and bold etc. When i googled it says i should use `CSS`.

How can i use `CSS`, to style the button that i added ?

My Question :

Where should i add the CSS file in my application, and how can i use it to style the button ?

```
items: [
                 {
                     xtype: 'button',
                     align: 'right',
                     text:'Assign' 
                 }
             ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
items: [
                 {
                     xtype: 'button',
                     align: 'right',
                     text:'Assign',
                     cls : 'foo' 
                 }
             ]
```

And in a CSS file:

```
.foo { background:black; }
```

This adds a CSS class to the outer most element of the Button. There may be many elements involved in the DOM markup, so use Firebug to figure out which elements you want to style.
More details in Ext docs: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-cfg-cls

Comment: Where should i add this CSS in the VIEW folder ?

Comment: Does not matter, put it in any folder.